# How do I declare an array of any type (derived from a given type) in an abstract class?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I'm not sure what the correct English words are for my problem, so I think it's best to illustrate it in code. I have a basic, abstract Windows Forms class that I use to create many derived Windows Forms that serve similar purposes. In the abstract base class, which we'll call `Alfred`, I have an array of type `Buddy`. Sometimes though, when I want to inherit `Alfred`, I also want to override class `Buddy` with some functionality specific to the new derived form, `AlfredJunior`.

So, in the definition of class `Alfred`:

```
protected Array<Buddy> importantArray;
```

And what I want in `AlfredJunior` is this:

```
private class BuddyJunior : Buddy
{
    public int newField;
    // Constructors omitted
}
protected Array<BuddyJunior> importantArray;
```

I'd like for the methods defined in `Alfred` to access and use the elements of `importantArray` just as if they were of type `Buddy`, instead of `BuddyJunior`. But I need just a touch of extra functionality (one extra field) in `BuddyJunior` in the inherited form `AlfredJunior`. What is the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
public abstract class Alfred<B> where B : Buddy
{
    protected B[] importantArray;
}

public class Buddy { }

public class BuddyJunior : Buddy
{
    public int newField;
}

public class Alfred : Alfred<Buddy> { }

public class AlfredJunior : Alfred<BuddyJunior> { }
```

Comment: Didn't know you could use the where keyword that way, thanks so much for the tip!

Comment: @bakester14 - Have a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: Hi @Enigmativity

I'm just looking over your code again now, I'm still working on this issue and I'm wondering if I can ask: what does the second to last line in the code you posted do?

Comment: @bakester14 - Do you mean the line `public class Alfred : Alfred<Buddy> { }`? It replaces your existing `Alfred` class.